# wrong import after updating go appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have updated goappengine to the last version and I have this error message. It looks like that it is looking for Go 1.4.2 and I am running 1.5.2 ??  It unlikely that I was running 1.4 before. 
Any pointers of the problem

```
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ goapp serve
INFO     2016-01-25 02:31:53,808 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-01-25 02:31:53,832 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:65025
INFO     2016-01-25 02:31:53,836 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-01-25 02:31:53,839 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-01-25 02:31:55,105 go_runtime.py:179] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /Users/moon/Downloads/d1/d2 -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot -nobuild_files ^^$ -unsafe -gopath /Users/moon/gopath:/Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot -binary_name _go_app -extra_imports appengine_internal/init -work_dir /var/folders/75/xlk18qb10231fqxqmdwg_xhm0000gn/T/tmpf1CeKbappengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine -ldflags -L,/Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64_appengine beta.go main.go)
/var/folders/75/xlk18qb10231fqxqmdwg_xhm0000gn/T/tmpf1CeKbappengine-go-bin/beta.go:9: import /Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/darwin_amd64/appengine.a: object is [darwin amd64 go1.5.2 X:none] expected [darwin amd64 go1.4.2 (appengine-1.9.31) X:precisestack]

2016/01/25 04:31:55 go-app-builder: build timing: 1×6g (11ms total), 0×6l (0 total)
2016/01/25 04:31:55 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1

^Cgoapp: caught SIGINT, waiting for dev_appserver.py to shut down
INFO     2016-01-25 02:32:19,423 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.
INFO     2016-01-25 02:32:19,423 api_server.py:648] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2016-01-25 02:32:19,423 api_server.py:651] Saving search indexes
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ goapp version
go version go1.4.2 (appengine-1.9.31) darwin/amd64
➜  dev git:(master) ✗ go version
go version go1.5.2 darwin/amd64
➜  dev git:(master) ✗
➜  dev git:(master) ✗echo $GOPATH
/Users/moon/gopath:/Users/moon/go_appengine/goroot
```

Comment: The appengine sdk requires go1.4.2, and you've recompiled some stuff in the sdk with go1.5. Just unpack a new version of the sdk, and don't manipulate anything in the sdk with your local go installation.

Comment: I don't think it requires 1.4.2.. but I could be wrong. I am using Go version 1.5.3 and I use appengine just fine (however I have the most recent version, whatever that is). Try what JimB said, just get a new version of the SDK.